# Change text in WordPress search bar

Tags: css, wordpress, searchbar

I need to change the text in the standard WordPress search bar from "Search this site" to just Search.  I haven't been able to figure it out.  Anyone know how?

Comment: did you try to make a custom form for the search?

Comment: I am using standard WordPress search bar.

Answer (score -1):

pls refer this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page. one way is to change text in placeholder attribute of input text

Comment: That is a little outside of my understanding.  Any more direction?